# VS 2008 + Intel Fortran questions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fortran

I'm using VS 2008 with Intel's Visual Fortran compiler. Its integration with VS is prettty good, but there are few things I'd still like to sort out. Hoping you could help me with some of them.

1. Is there a way to define new outlining (folding) rules in VS, so that it automatically folds from, let's say, CALL SUBROUTINE till END SUBROUTINE ?
2. Is there a way to redefine VS's keyboard shortcuts. I'd like to redefine commenting shortcut from default to something simpler, like Alt-C ?
3. I'm often making a project in which I have to add some additional dependencies under configuration properties, and some libraries as well. Is there a way I could define new project somehow (you know, when I go to New Project then I'd have MyNiceProject), so I have predefined those settings.
4. I've installed Intel's Array Visualizer. A nice thing as a standalone application, but when I go in debug mode, I can't seem to be able to visualize any array. The option "View Array" under Debug toolbar just stays greyed out. Any ideas ?

Help on any of these would be much appreciated.

I know these are 4 questions under the one title, but not many people use fortran with vs in here, so I thought it best not to "suffocate" the main page with 4 separate ones.

Answer (score 2):

I know one answer about the array visualizer, I bet your operating system is 64 bits. The array visualizer integration with VS 2008 does not work for the 64 operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dunno.
2. Yes - Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard
3. Dunno.
4. Dunno.

But my inadequate answers to your questions inspire me to try to find out a bit more.  I confess I usually use Emacs to edit Fortran source files, just use VS as a build tool for Windows.